# Display data from multiple tables PHP and MySQL in Yii

Tags: php, mysql, yii2

I tried displaying some info from multiple tables in my database using a query in PHPMyAdmin and it worked correctly.

All the searched info from the different tables appears in the result.

Here is the code:

```
SELECT name, sex, dob, city, meetingType_id, user.user_alt_id, profile_extra.value
from profile
INNER JOIN profile_meetingtype on profile.user_id = profile_meetingtype.profile_id
INNER JOIN user on profile_meetingtype.profile_id = user.id
INNER JOIN profile_extra on profile_extra.user_id = profile.user_id
INNER JOIN profile_field on profile_extra.field_id = profile_field.id
where user.id=10494
AND profile_extra.user_id=10494 AND (alias='religion' OR alias='political' OR alias='studies' OR alias='profession_company')
group BY user.id , value, meetingtype_id
```

But, when translating this code to PHP (I am using the framework Yii2), only the information from the first table "profile" appears. The other information from the tables mentioned in INNER JOIN doesn't appear.

```
$userInfo=Profile::find()
        -> select('name, sex, dob, city, meetingType_id, user.id, profile_extra.value')
        -> join('INNER JOIN', 'profile_meetingType', 'profile.user_id=profile_meetingType.profile_id')
        -> join('INNER JOIN', 'user', 'profile_meetingType.profile_id=user.id')
        -> join('INNER JOIN' , 'profile_extra', 'profile_extra.user_id=profile.user_id')
        -> join('INNER JOIN', 'profile_field', 'profile_extra.field_id=profile_field.id')
        -> where (['user.user_key_id'=>$keyId])
        -> where(['profile_extra.user_id' => $user->id, 'alias' => 'religion'])
        -> where(['profile_extra.user_id' => $user->id, 'alias' => 'political'])
        -> groupBy('user.user_key_id, profile_extra.value')
        -> all();
```

Is there something with the translation or is there something else to add to the code?

Comment: `when translating this code to PHP`...this looks like it's probably code from a specific ORM in a specific PHP framework. It's not raw PHP. Please mention which framework/ORM you are using as well.

Comment: Done! I am using the framework Yii2

Comment: It looks like `'name, sex, dob, city, meetingType_id, user.id, profile_extra.value'` is supposed to be an array, not a string

Answer (score 1):

I found the solution!

replace `->all();` by `-> createCommand();`

and then display the results with this line

```
$userResult = $userInfo->query();
```